# 301 rewrite / redirect rule results in 500 internal server error

Tags: .htaccess, iis, redirect, web-config, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect a specific page to another page using rewrite rule. However when ever I add the following code in the web config I get 500 internal server error.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="New Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="http://www.mydomain.com/terms" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
          </rule>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

I do not know much about redirection, however what I am doing is, let's say i have a domain `www.mydomain.com`, and if I have a specific url `www.mydomain.com/terms` i need to redirect it to home, that is `www.mydomain.com`

**UPDATE**

I have changed the rewrite rule as given, still able to access the page terms. The first part adding a www to non www based urls works fine , however not sure what is wrong in second rule.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>        
        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    <rule name="news redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="/terms" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the host from the match URL:

```
<match url="/terms" />
```

Comment: Dear Jon , I edited like this, still same error <rewrite>
      `<rules>
        <rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="/terms" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://127.0.0.1:81/" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>        
      </rules>
    </rewrite>`

Comment: @TBA you also seem to have 2 rules embedded within each other, get rid of the `<rule name="New Rewrite" enabled="true">` line and one of the `</rule>` lines

Comment: @TBA not sure, dunno if you need `<clear />`, other than that it looks fine

Comment: Hi That error has gone, however I am still able to access http://127.0.0.1:81/terms .

Comment: It got solved, only thing I missed was pattern should include www also.

Answer (score -1):

Download URL Rewrite Module 2.1
this should fix the 500 error
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite